# How could I kill an instance of cmd.exe that is running a particular batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, kill

If I'm running many instances of cmd.exe and only know the name of .bat file one of them executes, could I use taskkill to find and kill exact cmd.exe process?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another solution:

```
wmic process get caption,commandline,processid
```

I could see `.bat` file name as parameter for `cmd` invoked by at command.

Comment: I don't see anything in /V that the poster could use that'd do it. If you run a batch file like a.bat with the line pause, then try to find which cmd.exe is running it. your answer doesn't do that. i've improved his title

Comment: What system are you using? On my win2k3srv I can see 'Window Title' column and for CMD when you run command it appears on tittle bar.

Comment: As far as I can see it works pretty much like 'ps ax' in linux. So in my example I can see 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - tasklist /V' in this column.

Comment: barlop, actualy you are right.

Comment: (I use gnuwin32 hence grep), I did something like  tasklist /V | grep -i "bat"  so I saw pretty quickly it didn't show.. and I noticed a.bat doesn't show in task manager, i'm not sure if/where it shows in process explorer, but if it does then a cmd line version should do it though i don't know if it does or if there is one...

Comment: I thought original command solves issue but I tested it on bat files invoked from the console manualy. When bat file is invoked from task cheduler or by doubleclicking bat file then there is nothing on the list indicating what actualy is going on.. Anyway thanks for directing to better solution.

Comment: Well, I was going to suggest that you can include a `title` command in your batch files, it changes the title of the window.  `taskkill` can match on window title name if you use the `FI` switch: i.e. `taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq {window title name}" /F`

But it seems that the `title` command doesn't change what Windows internally considers the title, so it won't work.

Comment: @Greg0ry I have no solution

Comment: Even process explorer doesn't seem to show it, and I don't see it from sysinternals handle.exe.  I notice that you can delete a batch file before it has quit. Just tried a.bat with one line -pause-. And could delete it while it was running. Thus I see it doesn't get locked. I'm not sure how to detect that it's even open.

Comment: When I in one cmd window, run a.bat(which has one line- pause), then in another do something like your line- wmic process get caption,commandline,processid | find /i "bat" >output      Then I open the file, so, notepad output. Yes it has the string "bat" there but nothing useful. just as a parameter to find.  If however, I do cmd with /c or /k and a.bat, so those parameters with cmd, then both tasklist /v, and wmic show a.bat with cmd. But if you just open a cmd prompt and run a.bat then neither of those solutions work   to show a.bat  is being run. From my test anyway

Comment: By the way, the system is crazy, in that there is an issue or feature rather with adding new lines..as you noticed!  You may find that if you add 2 spaces at the end of a line then start the new line, then it works. Rather than <br> or <br />.